# Handling a 2-year subscription in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I need to be able to handle two types of subscriptions that Stripe doesn't seem to support out of the box:

1. A lifetime subscription
2. A two-year subscription

Lifetime subscription is easy. I'll just create a single charge and be done with it. It would've been nice to have a subscription record that I could check for validity.

Two-year subscription is where I am not sure what to do. I figure I'd create a one year subscription (current max in Stripe) and will have to use web hooks for when a new invoice will be generated. What would be the proper way of cancelling an upcoming charge? I am also worried that customers will receive an email alerting them for an upcoming charge in the middle of the period. Any way to avoid this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Stripe's [subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/quickstart) do not have a set end date. The 1 year maximum that you mention is the maximum [*interval*](https://stripe.com/docs/api#plan_object-interval), i.e. the frequency at which the customer will be billed.

If you want to end a subscription after a set number of payments, your best bet is to use [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to count the number of successful payments (via the [`invoice.payment_succeeded`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types-invoice.payment_succeeded) events) and [cancel the subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#cancel_subscription) when the desired number of payments has been reached.

Stripe does not send emails to customers about upcoming charges. It can optionally send [email receipts](https://stripe.com/docs/dashboard/receipts) after a charge is created, but you can disable this from your dashboard.

Comment: Thank you. I should've been more clear. I'm talking about intervals. I need a subscription billed every two years.

Comment: @AlexPolkhovsky Ah, thanks for the clarification. The maximum interval is 1 year, by design. Banks generally don't like subscriptions with longer intervals, because in many cases the customer will forget about it and dispute the charge.

Comment: It's frustratring that Stripe doesn't support "lifetime" subscriptions.

Comment: What do you mean @Frenchcooc? Can you give an example use case?

Comment: @Nolan I mean you have to handle a completely different API flow (subscription vs. payment) with different webhooks, while it would be much easier to be able to create a subscription with a lifetime value - lifetime plan are really common nowadays.

Comment: What do you mean by lifetime plan though? By default Stripe subscriptions will continue forever until you cancel them (or payment failures cause your settings to cancel them). If you mean "Pay one time and access forever" then you really don't need a Stripe subscription. You should just use a one-time Payment Intent and track your user subscription state in your own system. A Stripe subscription is meant to collect recurring payments based on your business model.